# How to disable a row in QTreeview?

Tags: user-interface, pyqt, treeview, pyside

I'm inheriting from `QtCore.QAbstractItemModel`, displaying a tree structure.

Below I'm trying to add an "enable/disable" feature for each node/row.

Does anyone know how to disable certain **rows** in a QTreeView Widget?

[image]

To be more clear, by "disable", I mean greyed out, still rightclickable, visible, not editable, like shown in the picture.

Comment: Have you already looked here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtreewidget.html
oops that posted before I could finish.. and here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtreewidgetitem.html
look at `itemAt()` in `QTreeWidget` and `setDisabled` in `QTreeWidgetItem`

Comment: @busfault OP is using qabstractitemmodel...That said, OP should be more clear: by 'disabled' do you mean to show but not be selectable? Or not show? Including a minimal self contained example might help (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Though I think most important with this one is including more precise specification of what you mean by 'disabled'.

Comment: Thank you guys for replying! And sorry for not being clear. I was trying to use the hierarchy to represent a parent-child relationship. If I right-click on joint2, I have two actions "enable, disable". I click on "disable" and joint2 and its children are greyed out but visible and right-clickable. Then, if I right click on joint2 and choose "enable", joint2 and its childeren are green and selectable/editable again.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of  `QTreeWidget` I used a treeView.

My code:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4 import QtCore

class TREEWIDGET (QtGui.QWidget):

def __init__(self):
    super(TREEWIDGET, self).__init__()        
    self.initUI()        

def initUI(self):

    self.treeView = QtGui.QTreeView (self)
    self.treeView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 311, 321))
    self.treeView.setObjectName('treeWidget')

    self.model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
    self.addItems(self.model)
    self.treeView.setModel(self.model)
    self.treeView.expandAll ()
    self.treeView.setSelectionMode (QtGui.QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)

    self.button_disable = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
    self.button_disable.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 340, 121, 23))
    self.button_disable.setObjectName('pushButton')
    self.button_disable.setText ('Disable')

    self.button_enable = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
    self.button_enable.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 340, 111, 23))
    self.button_enable.setObjectName('pushButton')
    self.button_enable.setText ('Ensable All')

    self.button_disable.clicked.connect (self.disable)
    self.button_enable.clicked.connect (self.enable)


    self.resize(350, 400)
    #self.addItems () 
    self.show()            

def addItems (self, parentWidget) :
    rootA        = QtGui.QStandardItem ('Joint1')
    parentWidget.appendRow (rootA)         
    cParent     = rootA      

    for loop in range (2, 6) :
        child   = QtGui.QStandardItem ('Joint' + str(loop))
        cParent.appendRow (child)         
        cParent     = child

    rootB        = QtGui.QStandardItem ('Joint_1')
    parentWidget.appendRow (rootB)         
    cParent     = rootB      

    for loop in range (2, 6) :
        child   = QtGui.QStandardItem ('Joint_' + str(loop))
        cParent.appendRow (child)         
        cParent     = child


def disable (self) :        
    selectedItem    = self.treeView.selectedIndexes  ()        
    for eachItem in selectedItem :   
        print   eachItem   
        currentItem     = eachItem.model().itemFromIndex(eachItem)
        currentItem.setEnabled(0)

def enable (self) :
    self.allItemElements    = [] 
    model           = self.treeView.model()        
    widget          = model.invisibleRootItem ()        
    existsItems     = self.collectItems (widget)

    for eachItem in existsItems :   
        eachItem.setEnabled(1)


def collectItems (self, widget) :
    itemCount   = widget.rowCount()         
    for itLoop in range (0, itemCount, 1) :            
        self.allItemElements.append (widget.child(itLoop))
        self.collectItems (widget.child(itLoop))                       
    return  self.allItemElements

def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = TREEWIDGET()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Hi, Subin. Thank you for your help again! It is very close to what I need!! However, once I disable an item, my right-click feature could not be triggered on that item anymore. But still, I'm new to treeviews, and thank you for sharing your knowledge with me!

Answer (score 2):

Override the `flags` method of your `QAbstractItemModel` descendant. Something like this:

```
def flags(self, index):

    if not index.isValid():
        return 0

    # Disable even rows, enable odd rows
    if index.row() % 2 == 0:
        return QtCore.Qt.NoItemFlags
    else:
        return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled
```

Answer (score 2):

This disables rows with all children (different from the other answer).

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4 import QtCore

class TREEWIDGET (QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(TREEWIDGET, self).__init__()        
        self.initUI()        

    def initUI(self):         
        self.treeWidget = QtGui.QTreeWidget(self)
        self.treeWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 311, 321))
        self.treeWidget.setObjectName('treeWidget')
        self.treeWidget.setSelectionMode (QtGui.QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)

        self.button_disable = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
        self.button_disable.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 340, 121, 23))
        self.button_disable.setObjectName('pushButton')
        self.button_disable.setText ('Disable')

        self.button_enable = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
        self.button_enable.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 340, 111, 23))
        self.button_enable.setObjectName('pushButton')
        self.button_enable.setText ('Ensable All')

        self.button_disable.clicked.connect (self.disable)
        self.button_enable.clicked.connect (self.enable)

        self.resize(350, 400)
        self.addItems () 
        self.show()          

    def addItems (self) :
        parentA = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem (self.treeWidget)
        parentA.setText (0, 'Joint1')   
        parentA.setExpanded (1)    
        cParentA    = parentA        
        for loop in range (2, 6) :
            childA = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem (cParentA)
            childA.setText (0, 'Joint' + str(loop)) 
            childA.setExpanded (1)
            cParentA     = childA

        parentB = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem (self.treeWidget)
        parentB.setText (0, 'Joint_1') 
        parentB.setExpanded (1)    
        cParentB     = parentB        
        for loop in range (2, 6) :
            childB = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem (cParentB)
            childB.setText (0, 'Joint_' + str(loop))
            childB.setExpanded (1)
            cParentB     = childB        

    def disable (self) :        
        selectedItem    = self.treeWidget.selectedItems ()
        for eachItem in selectedItem :
            eachItem.setDisabled (1)            
            eachItem.setSelected (0)     

    def enable (self) :  
        self.allItemElements    = [] 
        widget              = self.treeWidget.invisibleRootItem()
        existsItems         = self.collectItems (widget)          
        if existsItems :  
            for eachItem in existsItems :
                eachItem.setDisabled (0)         

    def collectItems (self, widget) :            
        itemCount           = widget.childCount ()       
        for itLoop in range (0, itemCount, 1) :
            self.allItemElements.append (widget.child(itLoop))
            self.collectItems (widget.child(itLoop))                       
        return  self.allItemElements

def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = TREEWIDGET()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: How is this different from the other answer you posted? not sure why you have two answers Subin...

Comment: In first code last some lines are missing, that why i posted once again.
There is not  different from the other. if you check both together u can understand. In second code, i append below code.

def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = TREEWIDGET()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

Comment: You should just delete the answer witht he mistake then. In the future, just edit your answer to correct it, don't put a new answer. That's the beauty of stack overflow! what we want is a single answer with a complete solution...Can you edit one of your answers to do that, and then delete the other answer, please?

Comment: This code works more like the picture in the question. Good work.

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4 import QtCore

class TREEWIDGET (QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(TREEWIDGET, self).__init__()        
        self.initUI()        

    def initUI(self):         
        self.treeWidget = QtGui.QTreeWidget(self)
        self.treeWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 311, 321))
        self.treeWidget.setObjectName('treeWidget')
        self.treeWidget.setSelectionMode (QtGui.QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)

        self.button_disable = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
        self.button_disable.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 340, 121, 23))
        self.button_disable.setObjectName('pushButton')
        self.button_disable.setText ('Disable')

        self.button_enable = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
        self.button_enable.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 340, 111, 23))
        self.button_enable.setObjectName('pushButton')
        self.button_enable.setText ('Ensable All')

        self.button_disable.clicked.connect (self.disable)
        self.button_enable.clicked.connect (self.enable)

        self.resize(350, 400)
        self.addItems () 
        self.show()          

    def addItems (self) :
        parentA = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem (self.treeWidget)
        parentA.setText (0, 'Joint1')   
        parentA.setExpanded (1)    
        cParentA    = parentA        
        for loop in range (2, 6) :
            childA = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem (cParentA)
            childA.setText (0, 'Joint' + str(loop)) 
            childA.setExpanded (1)
            cParentA     = childA

        parentB = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem (self.treeWidget)
        parentB.setText (0, 'Joint_1') 
        parentB.setExpanded (1)    
        cParentB     = parentB        
        for loop in range (2, 6) :
            childB = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem (cParentB)
            childB.setText (0, 'Joint_' + str(loop))
            childB.setExpanded (1)
            cParentB     = childB        

    def disable (self) :        
        selectedItem    = self.treeWidget.selectedItems ()
        for eachItem in selectedItem :
            eachItem.setDisabled (1)            
            eachItem.setSelected (0)     

    def enable (self) :  
        self.allItemElements    = [] 
        widget              = self.treeWidget.invisibleRootItem()
        existsItems         = self.collectItems (widget)          
        if existsItems :  
            for eachItem in existsItems :
                eachItem.setDisabled (0)         

    def collectItems (self, widget) :            
        itemCount           = widget.childCount ()       
        for itLoop in range (0, itemCount, 1) :
            self.allItemElements.append (widget.child(itLoop))
            self.collectItems (widget.child(itLoop))                       
        return  self.allItemElements
```

Comment: Subin, thank you for your response! :) One thing that is different from my original thinking, is that I'm using QTreeView and your code is using QTreeWidget. I'm trying to achieve what your disable() method does, but using QTreeView to display. This is how I'm getting the item. item = self.window.treeView.selectedIndexes()[0].internalPointer(). and QModelIndex() does not have a setDisable() func.

Comment: give me time i will help you.